# Problems with Angular state and resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I am working on learning the mean stack and am getting tripped up with Angular and routing. I have a javascript file, listed below that contains the routing code in the app.config module.

```js
var app = angular.module('doorSensorReadings', ['ui.router']);

app.factory('readings',  ['$http', function($http){
  var o = {
    readings: []
  };
  
  o.getAll = function() {
  alert("test");
 };
}])

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'readings', function($scope, readings){
  $scope.readings = readings.readings;  
 
  $scope.addReading = function(){
    $scope.readings.push({id: 2, name:"Door 4", open: true})
  }
  
}]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        Promise: ['readings', function(readings){
          return readings.getAll();
        }]
      }
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

When the page loads I would expect it to fire the code in the app.factory and send an alert box that says test. I can not figure out why the code is not being called and I am not getting any errors when I load the page. Right now it just simply loads a blank page. The "ejs" file is listed below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Angular App!</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="doorSensorReadings">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Door Sensor</h1>
    
    <div ng-repeat="reading in readings">
      {{reading.id}}, {{reading.name}}, {{reading.open}}
    </div>

    <button ng-click="addReading()">Post</button>
  </div>
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions as to why the alert is not being fired when the page is loaded would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `o` from `factory`, as factory return a object.

```
app.factory('readings',  ['$http', function($http){
  var o = {
    readings: []
  };

  o.getAll = function() {
     alert("test");
  };
  return o;
}])
```

Comment: So simple, Thank you.

Comment: @Chris Glad to help you.. Thanks :)